# Hola, tengo un problema al querer crear mi repositorio de github

Tags: git, bash, github, git-push, repositorio

como andan? Perdonen soy muy nuevo en esto y no estoy pudiendo resolverlo. Quizá me falte un paso.

Cuando trato de conectar mi proyecto a github con el add remote origin me salta un error y lo mismo al tratar de pushear

```
marco@DESKTOP-LKTM1PL MINGW64 ~/Desktop/margital (master)
$ git add remote origin https://github.com/MarcoPriani/margital.git
fatal: pathspec 'remote' did not match any files

marco@DESKTOP-LKTM1PL MINGW64 ~/Desktop/margital (master)
$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

Este es el error. Si alguno me puede ayudar lo agradeceria mucho!

Comment: Proba hacer un clone de tu repo primero...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

El comando para agregar un remoto es

```
git remote add
```

No

```
git add remote
```

Una vez que hayas resuelto eso (que agregues el remoto de forma correcta), el push te podría fallar también si en el repositorio en github ya tienes alguna revisión en la rama `master`. Y en ese caso, si quieres reemplazar lo que está en github por lo que tienes tu rama `master` local, tienes que hacer un force-push

```
git push -f -u origin master
```